# Xcode build script to create Icon.png and Default.png assets

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, bash, shell

I am building an application that exists of two different "versions". Each version has a different layout (different strings, images, colors and fonts). I accomplished this using macro's: there's one header file (let's call it Layout.h for now) that is included in all classes. Layout.h contains a `#define` statement that determines what version should be built. If this statement, let's call it `DARK_STYLE`, is true, `DarkStyle.h` is imported. If the statement is false, `BrightStyle.h` is included. Both `DarkStyle.h` and `BrightStyle.h` contain the same defines, but with different values. For example:

```
<DarkStyle.h>
#define TEXT_COLOR      [UIColor blackColor]

<BrightStyle.h>
#define TEXT_COLOR      [UIColor whiteColor]
```

So far so good. Now I have come to the point where the application has to be shipped. Unfortunately, each version has a different app icon and different splash screen. What I'm trying to do now is to get the app's Icon.png and Default.png files generated automatically based on the DARK_STYLE macro from Layout.h using an Xcode build script.

The build script I have at this point is able to determine whether DARK_STYLE is set to 1 or 0. The next step is the one I have trouble with: copy the Icon.png and Default.png assets belonging to the dark style to the application's bundle (the build script is executed after the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase).

The following does not work:

```
if find $SRCROOT -name "Layout.h" -exec echo {} \; -exec grep "#define DARK_STYLE" {} \; -exec grep 1 {} \;
then

# Copy dark style resources and rename them
find $SRCROOT -name "dark_icon.png" -exec cp "{}" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/" \;
mv "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/dark_icon.png" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Icon.png"

else
find $SRCROOT -name "bright_icon.png" -exec cp "{}" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/" \;
mv "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/bright_icon.png" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Icon.png"

fi
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: find will return a non zero exit status only in case of error.

Comment: The if statement seems to work as expected though...

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate build target in your Xcode project for each version of the app. Make sure each target includes the correct version of each asset.